# Adding child outside of didMove scope

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have came across a very unusual problem with - to my understand - swift 3. I am create a SpriteKit iOS game. The problem is with a `SKSpriteNode`. I create the node by

`var gameOverBackground : SKSpriteNode!`

This is located just inside the class. I then initialize the node in the `didMove()` function like so

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {        
    gameOverBackground = SKSpriteNode.init(texture: SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "UIbg")), size: CGSize(width: (self.scene?.size.width)! / 1.5, height: (self.scene?.size.height)! / 1.5))
    gameOverBackground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gameOverBackground.zPosition = 10
    gameOverBackground.name = "GameOverBackground"
}
```

Now the problem arises when I later try and add the node as a child to the scene. I am doing this in a contact function like so

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if (contact with many nodes) {
        self.addChild(self.gameOverBackground)
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error that the node is equal to `nil`. I have found a work around by just simply adding the child node in `didMove()` and making it hidden. Then just making it unhidden when contact happens; but I was more curious on why this problem is happening and if i'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are getting error because you are declaring the node as `var gameOverBackground : SKSpriteNode!` here you are implicitly unwrapping the optional and when you are using this in contact function your node is nil , so the error that node is equal to nil is thrown , to get rid of this you should declare the variable as non optional like `var gameOverBackground = SKSpriteNode()` or like this if you want it to be optional `var gameOverBackground : SKSpriteNode? = SKSpriteNode()` or simply `var gameOverBackground : SKSpriteNode?` but in this case it will still be nil but it wont crash

Comment: @3stud1ant3 your suggestion may work, but your reasoning is wrong :(  the  `!` simply tells the compiler "the programmer will ensure that this value is not nil when used" to allow them to initialize it somewhere else. The issue is that the node is nil, despite being initialized in didMove

Comment: @Fluidity thanks for your input, will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

> I have found a work around by just simply adding the child node in didMove() and making it hidden. Then just making it unhidden when contact happens; but I was more curious on why this problem is happening and if i'm doing something wrong.

This means that your node is notnil in didMove, but then somewhere along the way has become nil by the time of your contact delegate.

Here is an example of your code, only simplified a bit:

```
var node: SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
  node = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
}

// Touchesbegan on ios:
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
  addChild(node)
}
```

The code runs fine and when you click the screen the node appears.

Touchesbegan / didBegin won't make a difference.

The issue is that somewhere in your code the node is getting set to nil.

Here is an example of how that could happen:

```
// Touchesended on ios:
override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
  node.removeFromParent() // or, node = nil
  addChild(node) // crash!!
}
```